# how can I use cAdvisor to collect IP information?

Tags: docker, cadvisor

I want to use cAdvisor to build a monitor system, and this system will be used to collect the information of docker containers, but now I have a problem: I can't collect IP address information. So how can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @yamenk No errors,it can work normally. But I don't know how to let it collect IP address information. It just can collect the hostname.